# Multiple side menu on same page not working Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to create 2 menus on a page in Ionic2

app.html

```
    <ion-menu [content]="content" side="right" id="menu1">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item menuClose="menu1" detail-none>
        Close Menu 1
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-menu [content]="content" side="left" id="menu2">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item  menuClose="menu2" detail-none>
        Close Menu 2
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

hello-ionic.html:

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Hello Ionic</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <p>
    <button ion-button color="secondary" menuToggle="left">Toggle Main Menu</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button ion-button color="primary" menuToggle="right">Toggle Menu</button>
  </p>
</ion-content>
```

The problem I am facing is that only menu2 is working, menu1 is not appearing. If I delete menu2 than menu1 is working.

Please help

Comment: Could you please tell us what specifically is not working? I've just used your code in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LyjB5gQw041HE6OmVyYB?p=preview) and works properly. The only thing to mention is that the `menuToggle` in the header does not specify which one should open, so it does not work, but the buttons in the content work properly because they specify the left or right menu by doing `menuToggle="left"` or `menuToggle="right".`

Comment: @sebaferreras I was thinking may have to set menuToggle as menu id with multiple menus..I guess it works without it too...

Comment: @SurajRao, yeah, you can specify the side or the id; it works properly in both ways.

Comment: @sebaferreras 23 , only one one menu button works, other don. I will try code on another PC & will record the screen to precisely explain my problem

Answer (score 0):

I also have problems like you
    And my solution is

file `app.html` edit like:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="left" id="menu1">
   This is menu 1 
</ion-menu>
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="right" type="overlay" id="menu2">  
   This is menu 2
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" [rootParams]="rootParams" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

file `app.component.ts`

```
add in constructor() {
   ...
   this.menu.enable(true, 'menu1');
   this.menu.enable(true, 'menu2');
}
```

USING: 
`PAGE.html`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="mytheme">
    <button ion-button menuToggle="left" start>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>PAGENAME</ion-title>
    <button ion-button menuToggle="right" end>
      <ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Wish you success :)))))))